# ExtJs Chart, How to get boundary dates from selection mask on 'Time' type axis

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs4.2

I have ExtJs 4 Area chart with Time serie. I'd like user to be able to horizontally select part of chart and then obtain higher density data from server adequately. Problem is I can't get boundary dates from selection. I've got:

```
var chart = Ext.create('Ext.chart.Chart', {
  store: store,
  enableMask: true,
  mask: 'horizontal',
  listeners: {
    select: {
        fn: function(me, selection) {
            console.log(arguments); // selection = Object { height: 218, width: 117, x: 665, y: 123 }
        }
    },
  ...
```

But select listener provides only pixel data. Is there some way to get boundary axis data (e.g. { from: 2013-08-01, to: 2013-08-20 } or some way to unproject pixels to values? I'm desperade I would say it's such a basic thing but can't find solution anywhere. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well.. it probably doesn't exists a method for this. After digging into source code I've utilized lines from chart.setZoom() method to create function for manual unprojecting of mask selection to X axis data:

```
var unprojectXAxis = function(chart, selection) {
  zoomArea = {
    x : selection.x - chart.el.getX(),
    width : selection.width
  };

  xScale = chart.chartBBox.width,

  zoomer = {
      x : zoomArea.x / xScale,
      width : zoomArea.width / xScale
  }

  ends = chart.axes.items[0].calcEnds();
  from = (ends.to - ends.from) * zoomer.x + ends.from;
  to = (ends.to - ends.from) * zoomer.width + from;

  return { from: new Date(from), to: new Date(to) };
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, except `items[1]` for me as it depends on the order you declare them inside the chart object.